# C++ Function will not call last parameter

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I have an assignment where I must display the subject, cost, total and cheapest textbook of a college bookstore. I must read data from an input file and pass parameters through various functions to complete this. I've managed to get the first 4 subjects to pass and display, but the last one, mathematics, will not read from the input file and will not display. The Error I get is: "Debug assertion failed". I've attached the full error and the output of my program. Below is my code. Any help or hints are appreciated, as I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours now. Thanks.

[The output and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yPSb.png)

```
enter code here
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

void print_output(int text_num, double t1, double t2, double t3, double tot, 
int num, double cheap_one);

using namespace std;

int main() {

string  store_name;
string subject;

// define variables

ifstream inData;
ofstream outData;

string Biology, Chemistry, English, Computer, Mathematics;
double text1, text2, text3;
double total1;
double small;
double text_num = 1;
double num = 1;

cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

// print titles here like dereks bookstore and the subjects plus 
text/cheapest 

cout << "Derek's Bookstore" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Subject\t" << setw(5) << "    Text 1\t" << "Text 2\t" << "Text 3\t" 
<< "Total\t" <<
    "    Cheapest/Amount\t" << endl;
cout << endl;

    inData.open("first_project_data.txt");
    if (!inData) {
    cout << "\nCannot open input file." << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
   inData >> subject;

   while (inData) {
    //cout << "\n\n**at beginning" << subject << endl << endl;
    inData >> text1 >> text2 >> text3;

    // calculate totals

    total1 = text1 + text2 + text3;

    // find out the cheapest book (use if statement )
    small = text1;
    if (text1 > text2)
        small = text2;
    if (small > text3)
        small = text3;

    // call the print function

    //cout << text1 << " Before print" << total1;
    //system("PAUSE");

    print_output(text_num, text1, text2, text3, total1, num, small);

    text_num++;
    inData >> subject;

    }


     //cout << "\n\n**at end" << subject << endl << endl;


   // output the last total line
   inData.close();
   outData.close();
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
   }

   void print_output(int subject, double t1, double t2, double t3, double 
   tot, int num, double cheap_one) {
   char text_name[8], subject_name[10];

switch (subject) {

case 1: strcpy_s(subject_name, "Biology");
    break;
case 2: strcpy_s(subject_name, "Chemistry");
    break;
case 3: strcpy_s(subject_name, "English");
    break;
case 4: strcpy_s(subject_name, "Computer");
    break;
case 5: strcpy_s(subject_name, "Mathematics");
    break;
}
switch (num) {


case 1: strcpy_s(text_name, "text1");
    break;
case 2: strcpy_s(text_name, "text2");
    break;
case 3: strcpy_s(text_name, "text3");
    break;
 }
cout << setw(12) << left << subject_name << t1 << "\t" << t2 << "\t" << t3 
<< "\t" << tot << "\t\t"
    << text_name << "/$ " << cheap_one << endl;

}
```

Comment: You don't check that `inData >>` worked in your loop. `while (inData) {` doesn't guarantee that the next read(s) will work.

Comment: From the non-standard `strcpy_s` it looks like you're using Visual Studio. There's an amazing debugger in Visual Studio that should stop and allow you to gather information when the assertion hits. I recommend taking advantage.

Comment: Normally when you get an error like that you press Retry. Then walk up the callstack to your code to see the line in your code that triggered the assert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your char array subject_name is 10 chars long, but "Mathematics" needs 12 chars (including the trainling null).

strcpy_s detects this situation and reports this as the assertion you saw. Therefore this function is preferrable over the unchecked strcpy which will just silently produce a buffer overrun which may crash our program if you are lucky or represent a security hole.

Instead of having to deal with char array sizes, I would recommend using std::string.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you! Please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so it can help other people checking this question, too.